# When and why to use performSelector - iOS

Tags: ios5, methods, performselector

I have been trying to figure out why and how to use performSelector. 
I did come across [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html). However, I am not able to fully understand it.

Would anyone be able to help me out in explaining this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Apple's documentation:

> the performSelector: method allows you to send messages that aren’t
>   determined until runtime

Longer story:

You can send messages to objects without prior knowledge of whether the object implements this particular method. For example:

```
NSString *astring = @"test";

[test dance]; // Doesn't compile
[test performSelector:@selector(dance)]; // Doesn't make sense but compiles
```

Comment: thank you.. thats makes sense.. would you be able to give me an example of where I would use performSelector on an object that does implement a method?

Comment: For example when you want to execute a method in the background:
`[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(myMethod) withObject:nil];`

Comment: thanks for the reply. so when would I use performSelector as compared to just calling a method?

Comment: Mainly in methods like the one in my example that take other methods (selectors) as arguments. (Think of it as a 'pointer' to a method)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, using the selector is a way to declare the `callback method` as what we did on Java, C#, ... Suppose that you develop library A, which do an asynchronous calculate and return result whenever it done. At development time, you don't know what call back method you should call whenever the calculating done. So you can make the library get an `selector` as input parameter and use `performSelector` later to invoke callback methods.

Hope this helps.